# How can I break the while loop and go to the finally block if the user entered "done"

Tags: python, python-3.x, try-except

```
largest = None
smallest = None
l = []
while True:
    try:
        num = input("Enter a number: ")
    except NameError as err:
        if err == "done":
            break
        else:
            print("Invalid input")
    finally:
        l.append(num)
        l.sort()
        largest = l[-1]
        smallest = l[0]


print("Maximum", largest)
print("Minimim", smallest)
```

Comment: how is the `except` every going to be triggered?

Comment: Why use finally at all? Why not sort and calculate the smallest/largest in the "done" processing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Comment: You need to redesign your logic. A `NameError` will never happen, and it will never be equal to `'done'`. As well, `l.sort()` and everything after should be outside of the loop.

Comment: no cuz' he uses ValueError and I want to use NameError as exception

Comment: If your objective is to get the smallest and largest, uou can just use 2 variables, current min and current max. There is no need for the list and sort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code looks like it's for Python 2.x, where `input()` tried to evaluate the input, and signalled an error if you typed a string that's not a variable name. Python 3.x doesn't signal an error when you type `done`.

So just compare the input. You can later do error checking when you try to convert it to an `int`.

```
while True:
    num = input("Enter a number")
    if num == "done":
        break
    try:
        num = int(num)
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid input")
        continue
    l.append(num)
l.sort()
largest = l[-1]
smallest = l[0]
```

Comment: @AnasGhareib Make sure you're using Python 3 as your tagging indicates.

Answer (score 1):

Refactored logic.  `NameError` won't happen and `finally` not needed...just put it outside the while when "finally" done.

```
nums = []

while True:
    num = input('Enter a number or "done": ')  # num is a string at this point
    if num == 'done':
        break
    try:
        # try to convert num to integer...
        num = int(num)  # This can fail with ValueError, so is in try
        nums.append(num)   # This won't run if above raises exception
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid input")

# No need to sort...
print("Maximum", max(nums)) 
print("Minimum", min(nums))
```

Comment: Ideally `l.append(num)` should be in an `else` clause, but nbd

Comment: @wjandrea six of one, half dozen of the other...one less line of code :)

Comment: @AnasGhareib Which version of Python are you using?